# Neo4j 2.0.0 - Poor performance for dev/test in a virtual machine

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have Neo4j server running inside a virtual machine using Ubuntu 13.10 and I am accessing via  REST using Cypher queries. The virtual machine has 4 GB of memory allocated to it.

I've changed the open file count to 40000, set the initial JVM heap to 1G and my `neo4j.properties` file is as follows:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=250M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=100M

keep_logical_logs=3 days

node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=id
```

I've also updated sysctl based on the Neo4j Linux tuning guide:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 50
vm.dirty_ratio = 80
```

Since I am testing queries, the basic routine is to run my suite of tests and then delete all of the nodes and run them all again. At the start of each test run, the database has 0 nodes in it. My suite of tests of about 100 queries is taking 22 seconds to run. Basic parameterized creates such as:

```
CREATE (x:user { email: {param0},
  name: {param1},
  displayname: {param2},
  id: {param3},
  href: {param4},
  object: {param5} })
CREATE x-[:LOGIN]->(:login { password: {param6},
  salt: {param7} } )
```

are currently taking over 170ms to execute (and that's the average, first query time is 700ms). During a test run, the CPU in the VM never exceeds 50% and memory usage is at a steady 1.4Gb.

Why would creating a single node in an empty database take 170ms?  At this point unit testing is becoming almost impossible since it is so slow. This is my first time trying to tune Neo4j so I'm not really sure how to figure out where the problem is or what changes should be made.

**Additional Details**

I'm using Go 1.2 to make REST calls to the `cypher` endpoint (`http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`) of a locally installed Neo4j instance. I'm setting the request headers for content-type to "application/json", accept to "application/json" and "X-Stream" to true. I always return either an array of maps or nothing depending on the query.

It seems like the creates are the problem and are taking forever. For example:

```
2014/01/15 11:35:51 NewUser took 123.314938ms
2014/01/15 11:35:51 NewUser took 156.101784ms
2014/01/15 11:35:52 NewUser took 167.439442ms
2014/01/15 11:35:52 ValidatePassword took 4.287416ms
```

NewUser creates two new nodes and one relationship and is taking 167ms, while ValidatePassword is a read-only operation and it completes in 4ms. Also note that the three calls to NewUser are identical parameterized queries. While the creates are the big problem, I'm also a little concerned that Neo4j is taking 4ms to just find a labeled node when there are only 100 nodes in the database.

I do not restart the server in between test runs or delete the database. I issue a single delete all nodes query `MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r` at the end of the test run. Running the same test suite multiple times back to back does not improve the query times.

Comment: Extended my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your 100 queries all the same only with different parameters, or actually 100 different queries?

What you see is actually setup work. The parser has to load the parsing rules initially that takes a few ms. Also new queries that have not been seen are compiled, planned and put in the query cache.

So the first query always takes a bit longer. But as you parametrize all subsequent ones should be fast.

Can you confirm that?

I think you see the [transactional overhea](http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/)d of flushing the transaction to disk.

Did you try to batch more requests into one? I.e. with the transactional endpoint? Or the /db/data/batch (but I'd rather use the new tx-endpoint /db/data/transaction).

Did you create an index for your lookup property for your validate query?

Can you do me a favor and test your create query without a label? I found some perf issues when testing that myself earlier this week.

Just ran a test with curl

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do time curl -i -H content-type:application/json -H accept:application/json -H X-Stream:true -d @perf_test.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher; done
```

I'm getting between 16 and 30ms per request externally including starting curl

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8; stream=true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)

{"columns":[],"data":[]}
real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.005s
```

Perhaps it is rather the VM (disk or network) or the cross-vm communication?

Did another test with ab and 1000 requests for both endpoints, got a mean of about 5 ms both times.

https://gist.github.com/jexp/8452037

Comment: The queries within the test suite are mostly unique, but I'm running the same exact test suite over and over again which should cache the execution plans (I hope?). In the first run of the test suite after starting Neo4j a basic create can take 700ms, subsequent runs are taking 170ms. Seems 700ms for first run is still crazy long, but I can live with that if the subsequent ones are fast.

Comment: Do you restart the server in between? And what kind of driver do you use? Or do you call the REST endpoint yourself? If this is 2.0 I recommend using the transactional endpoint. Perhaps you can share more details about how you execute your queries?

Comment: I've added some more details to the question above.

Comment: No change if I remove the labels. I'm not trying to do a large data import, I'm literally trying to insert 2 nodes and 1 relationship which is all done in a single Cypher query. There is nothing to batch. Is there any way to tell Neo4j to not flush to disk? Also, I have created an index for my lookup property on the validate query.

Comment: By nothing to batch, I mean each test is independent. Each test runs a single Cypher query synchronously and then validates the results before moving on to the next test. This is for a web service and so this is how it will work in production as well - I can't wait for a bunch of requests to come in and try to batch them before responding.

Comment: I will try to profile this on my side too. Probably with `ab` so that there is no driver in between

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm not using any driver just straight REST calls. I can send you the exact calls I'm making if that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm getting 90Mb/s read and write on my disk and the Neo4j database is local to my tests (i.e. no VM to VM communication or network involved). I've opened a new Neo4j issue in GitHub because something is obviously wrong, I should be able to get more than 7.5 inserts per second when I can push more than 300 inserts per second on Postgres with the same VM.